# Fireauth phone authentication is not working all of sudden

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

When user press phone authentication this below code is executed.

```
   void verifyPhoneFireAuth() async {
    final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final authPhoneNumber = "+82 10${_selectedPhone.toString().substring(4)}";
    await firebaseAuth
        .verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: authPhoneNumber,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
      verificationCompleted: (phoneAuthCredential) async {
        // Android only
        await firebaseAuth
            .signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)
            .then((value) {
          if (mounted) {
            setState(() {
              _donePhone = true;
              _requestPhoneAuthSms = false;
              _doneVerification = true;
              _verificationResult = "‍♀️ 자동 인증되었습니다.";
            });
          }
        });
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException error) {
        if (error.code == "invalid-phone-number") {
          setState(() {
            _donePhone = true;
            _requestPhoneAuthSms = false;
            _doneVerification = true;
            _verificationResult = "‍♀️ 잘못된 휴대폰 번호입니다.";
          });
        }

        if (error.code == "network-request-failed") {
          setState(() {
            _donePhone = true;
            _requestPhoneAuthSms = false;
            _doneVerification = true;
            _verificationResult = "‍♀️ 네트워크 상태를 확인해주세요.";
          });
        }
      },
      codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            _verificationId = verificationId;
          });
        }
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {},
    )
        .catchError((error) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("verifyPhoneNumber -> $error");
    });
  }
```

I checked that sms code is successfully sent to user.

And I store `verificationId` to _verificationId in codeSent part.

Then if user type smsCode and press button, below code will be executed.

```
 Future<void> _submitSmsCode() async {
    closeKeyboard(context);
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    _timer.cancel();

    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      verificationId: _verificationId,
      smsCode: _phoneSmsController.text,
    );

    try {
      final user = await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _donePhone = true;
          _requestPhoneAuthSms = false;
          _doneVerification = true;
          _verificationResult = "‍♀️ 인증에 성공했습니다.";
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print

      if (e.toString().contains("firebase_auth/invalid-verification-code")) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            _donePhone = true;
            _requestPhoneAuthSms = false;
            _doneVerification = true;
            _verificationResult = "‍♀️ 맞지 않은 인증번호입니다.";
          });
        }
      } else {
        if (!mounted) return;
        showErrorSnackBar(context, "문제가 발생했습니다.\n다시 한번 시도해주세요.");

        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

But I checked that `await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)` throws error.

It works well in debug mode with test code. But in production, users always are stopped.

The error that I barely checked from debug mode was

`[firebase_auth/channel-error] Unable to establish connection on channel`

And user says that if user go back to previous screen and try one more time it works.

Even though I install `firebase crashlytics`, this blocks build of ios with issue, so I can't.

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/6623

I've struggled with this issue for almost a month and production users can't be signed in..

But I really can't find any issue from my code.

Please please help me.